# Calling a file in python

Tags: python

I'd like to call a .py file from within python. It is in the same directory. Effectivly, I would like the same behavior as calling python foo.py from the command line without using any of the command line tools. How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite clear (at least to me) what you mean by using "none of the command-line tools".

To run a program in a subprocess, one usually uses the `subprocess` module. However, if both the calling and the callee are python scripts, there is another alternative, which is to use the `multiprocessing` module.

For example, you can organize foo.py like this:

```
def main():
    ...

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Then in the calling script, test.py:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import foo
proc=mp.Process(target=foo.main)
proc.start()
# Do stuff while foo.main is running
# Wait until foo.main has ended
proc.join()    
# Continue doing more stuff
```

Comment: @jathanism: That's quite possible :) Though, I like calling functions (which mp.Process allows) much more than calling python scripts (through subprocess) which then need to be optparsed/argparsed.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. I am only just now getting into multiprocessing and I'm happy to see such a basic usage of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
execfile('foo.py')
```

See also:

- [Further reading on execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile)

Answer (score 3):

`import module` or `__import__("module")`, to load module.py.

- [Modules - Python v2.7 documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)
- [Importing Python modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)